# getLastVisiblePosition returning -1

Tags: android, listview, android-cursor

I'm having a problem with my `ListView` (using `CursorAdapte`r).  When I call `getListView().getLastVisiblePosition()` I am receiving `-1`.  This is a problem since my list is populated with items.  Additionally, `getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition()` always returns 0, no matter where I am scrolled on the list.  Any ideas?

It has something to do with startManagingCursor

```
    @Override
    public void changeCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        super.changeCursor(cursor);
        MyActivity.this.mCursor = cursor;
        //startManagingCursor(MyActivity.this.mCursor);
    }
```

If I comment out startManagingCursor, everything works fine.  I've also tried adding `stopManagingCursor()` before changing the `Cursor` and still have the same problem.

Comment: Can anyone offer any additional ideas?  Id really like to be using startManagingCursor

Comment: Is the listview already populated when you call `.getLastVisiblePosition()`?

Answer (score 34):

This is because the moment you call getListView().getLastVisiblePosition() the listview is not rendered. You can add the call to the view's message queue like this:

```
listview.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        listview.getLastVisiblePosition();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Even I faced the same problem. The thing is that, getLastVisiblePosition() works only when you are in the first element of your listview and for the rest you will get null being returned. So what I did is that, I made a small calculation to find out the exact view position which I have mentioned below,

```
int  LastPos=(mylist.getLastVisiblePosition()-mylist.getFirstVisiblePosition());
```

This returns the exact last position without a doubt.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your `getItem(int position)` and `getItemId(int position)` methods aren't defined correctly in your adapter.

Comment: They aren't defined at all.  They never have been.  This was all working fine before until I started using startManagingCursor (because I was receiving "Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed" errors).  I also don't see how those two methods would affect this.  I'm asking Android for the first and last visible positions; not for the data.

Comment: Yeah, and I'm sure that getLastPosition() uses those 2 methods to determine that information

Comment: Why would it?  Also, since I'm not overriding these methods, why would everything work fine when I dont startManagingCursor, but fail once I do?  In both cases, I have not overrode these methods