# getLastVisiblePosition returning -1 in fragment

Tags: android

I have a listfragment, whose listview is loaded using a cursorloader from the contacts provider.

**Requirement** : I need to use view.getLastVisiblePosition() once when the listview is loaded for the first time and also every time there is a scroll.

**Problem** : view.getLastVisiblePosition works in the onScrollListener, but it always returns -1 in onActivityCreated() or onCreateView() or onViewCreated().

**Code** :

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // Set up ListView, assign adapter and set some listeners. The adapter was previously
        // created in onCreate().
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

        final ListView v = getListView();

        v.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        v.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int scrollState) {
                // Pause image loader to ensure smoother scrolling when flinging
                if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING) {
                    mImageLoader.setPauseWork(true);
                } else {
                    mImageLoader.setPauseWork(false);
                }

                if (scrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    evaluateInviteView();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
        });



        if (mIsTwoPaneLayout) {
            // In a two-pane layout, set choice mode to single as there will be two panes
            // when an item in the ListView is selected it should remain highlighted while
            // the content shows in the second pane.
            v.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        }

        // If there's a previously selected search item from a saved state then don't bother
        // initializing the loader as it will be restarted later when the query is populated into
        // the action bar search view (see onQueryTextChange() in onCreateOptionsMenu()).
        if (mPreviouslySelectedSearchItem == 0) {
            // Initialize the loader, and create a loader identified by ContactsQuery.QUERY_ID
            getLoaderManager().initLoader(ContactsQuery.QUERY_ID, null, this);
        }

evaluateInviteView();
    }

 private void evaluateInviteView(){
        final ListView v = getListView();
        int LastVisiblePosition = v.getLastVisiblePosition();
        Log.d("faizal","inside : " + LastVisiblePosition );
    }
```

A similar question, in another context, was asked at [getLastVisiblePosition returning -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036676/getlastvisibleposition-returning-1). One solution suggested there was to execute view.getLastVisiblePosition() inside a runnable. But that also returns -1 for me.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I generally use this to get lastvisibleposition

```
list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

     @Override
     public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
             int scrollState) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         int threshold = 1;
         int count = list.getCount();

         if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
             if (list.getLastVisiblePosition() >= count
                     - threshold) {
                //do your stuff

             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: Using the getLastVisiblePosition() in the onScrollListener works for me as well. The problem is it is not working in any of the lifecycle methods onActivityCreated() or onCreateView() or onViewCreated(). Maybe the listview is initialized only sometime after these methods? If so, I am wondering which lifecycle method would it be initialized in?

Comment: can you post the code of your activity, because i am also using the same thing in onCreateView() and it is working very well

Comment: that's wierd. I have posted the code in the question. The evaluateInviteView() function is where i call getLastVisiblePosition(). I have removed most of the irrelevant code for the sake of brevity. The result is the same if i call evaluateInviteView() from onCreateView() or onViewCreated().

Comment: How did you manage to access the listview in onCreateView() ? If i do a getListView() there, it just crashes with "Error inflating class fragment".

Comment: I am using customListadapter for populating the listview and the adapter using list.setadapter()

Answer (score 0):

I too was having this problem, and I was pulling my hair out. The solution is contained within here: [getLastVisiblePosition returning -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036676/getlastvisibleposition-returning-1)

It takes some time for the `ListView` items to actually populate and therefore the call to `getLastVisiblePosition()` will return -1 until that happens. The solution is to post a new `Runnable` to the `Listview` with all of the code dependent on the last visible position, and execute everything within the `Runnable`.

For example, some code I was writing to dynamically modify the TextView in each list item:

```
list.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int start = list.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        int last = list.getLastVisiblePosition();
        for (int i = start; i <= last; i++) {
            View vv = list.getChildAt(i-start);
            View v = list.getAdapter().getView(i, vv, list);
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_text);
            // other stuff...
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: As mentioned at the end of my question, using a runnable didn't work for me.